# Computer science corpus for training a language model

Tags: nlp, data-mining, text-mining, text, corpus

I am looking for a **domain specific computer science corpus** of at least 20M words (preferable >50M words), for the purpose of training a language model in it.

Is there anything out-of-the box that I could use? 
*I tried to look for the sciBERT corpus, can not find how to access it.

Thanks!

Comment: Try asking on [OpenData.StackExchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the domain and language, but I'll share an adaptive example.

The [wikipedia corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/wiki/)'s English version contains more than 1.9 billion words from 4.4 million articles.

You can create create [virtual corpora](https://www.english-corpora.org/wikipedia.asp) from the full corpus to contain only topics of interest, such as biology, investments, Buddhism, psychology, cars, basketball, etc.

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to do a web-crawl for that or is there a simpler way to do that that you can refer me to? 
* I don't have any experience with complicated methods for data mining, that's why I'm looking for "out of the box" corpus.

Comment: @user Go to [this link](https://www.english-corpora.org/corpora.asp) and here you can download the dataset.

Comment: I also used the reddit API a while back to get a [20M word corpus of jokes posted in 2019](https://github.com/wonhyukchoi/redditjokes/blob/master/2019_reddit_jokes.csv), if that's something that interests you.

Comment: I need a *computer science* related corpus, can not see there something like that, but I really appreciate you answers.